# How can I compare two lists of uints and calculate the difference in any values?

Tags: c#

I have two lists of `uint` type called `firstReadOfMachineTotals` and `secondReadOfMachineTotals`

I'm completely new to C# programming.

I would like to compare both lists and, if any of the values in the second list are higher than the first list, calculate by how much.

For instance...

```
firstReadOfMachineTotals = 10, 20, 4000, 554
secondReadOfMachineTotals = 10, 40, 4000, 554
```

I want to return '20' (based on the second item being 20 more than the equivalent in the first list).

Thanks

PS. There will never be more than one number different in the second list.

Comment: Did you try anything? It can be beautifully done in a single line of code using LINQ FirstOrDefault + null-propagation, but it would be **useless** for you because you won't learn anything yourself. You need to try to do it yourself using simple loops and ifs - just iterate through your indices and compare two values.

Comment: And if you had another higher number in the second list? what would you return the sum of them? or a list of differences?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten good question, I should have pointed it out, unless there is an issue with the other code then there should never be two numbers different. I'll edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I did play around with looping through the lists with foreach() but it just seemed like such a kludge I presumed there would be a more elegant way. I didn't mention that I'd tried foreach() in the main question as I wanted to extricate as many answers as I could in order to glean as much information as I could on the correct way(s) to do this. I didn't want to exclude any potential answer as the more I can read the more I'll learn. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Zip`, `Where`:

```
var firstReadOfMachineTotals = new[]{ 10, 20, 4000, 554 };
var secondReadOfMachineTotals = new[]{ 10, 40, 4000, 554};

var result = firstReadOfMachineTotals.Zip(secondReadOfMachineTotals, (a,b) => b > a ? b - a : 0)
                        .Where(x => x > 0)
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x)
                        .FirstOrDefault();

Console.WriteLine(result); // output = 20
```

This method will default to `0` when all values are the same. If instead you wanted control of this default you could also do:

```
var firstReadOfMachineTotals = new[]{ 10, 20, 4000, 554 };    
var secondReadOfMachineTotals = new[]{ 10, 40, 4000, 554};


var result = firstReadOfMachineTotals.Zip(secondReadOfMachineTotals, (a,b) => b > a ? b - a : 0)

                        .Where(x => x>0)
                        .DefaultIfEmpty(int.MinValue) // or whatever default you desire
                        .Max();

Console.WriteLine(result); // output = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

You can index into the lists and simply take the difference of each element at the specified index then sum the difference to retrieve the result.

```
int result = Enumerable.Range(0, Math.Min(list1.Count, list2.Count))
                       .Select(i => list2[i] - list1[i] <= 0 ? 0 : list2[i] - list1[i]).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var result = firstReadOfMachineTotals.Zip(secondReadOfMachineTotals,
                (f, s) =>  s > f ? s - f : 0).Where(f => f > 0).DefaultIfEmpty(-1).Max();
```

Comment: @S.Akbari well you got an upvote from me. Thanks for the solution I'll try this when I get home from work. Just having a read about "Zip" now to try and understand how your solution will work. Cheers :-)

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution will be to sort both the arrays

```
array1.sort()
array2.sort()
```

and compare each indexes and take action

```
for(int i=0;i<array1.lenght;i++)
  {
  if(array1[i] < array2[i])
  {
     // Specify your action.
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you mistake this for a javascript question?

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this is the following:

```
int difference = arr1
    .Zip(arr2, (a, b) => (int?)Math.Max(b - a, 0))
    .SingleOrDefault(d => d != 0) ?? 0;
```

It returns the difference if there is an element in the second collection which is larger than its corresponding element from the first collection.
If there isn't any, it returns zero.

Information to read:

**[LINQ Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx)**
**[LINQ FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx)**
**[?? Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)**
**[Nullable Types (int?)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/index)**

Comment: An int is never null so you can't use `??`

Comment: This looks great. I'll give it a go when I get home from work. And thanks very much for the links to the LINQ info. I'll read and digest. Cheers :-)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Of course, you are right. I have updated my solution with cast to `int?` and it doesn't look elegant anymore. Anyway, it solves the problem and may be useful for the OP :)